# Twin Prime Stream

Tags: stream, scheme, primes

I want to generate a stream of twin primes such that the stream would be as follows

```
((3 5) (5 7) (11 13) (17 19) ...)
```

and so on. I have a function that generates a stream of prime numbers, and a function that pairs them together. Where I'm confused is how to alter my pairing function so that only twin primes are paired together. My pairing function is:

```
(define (pairs s t)
    (cons-stream
        (list (stream-car s) (stream-car t))
        (interleave
            (stream-map (lambda (x) (list (stream-car s) x))
                (stream-cdr t))
            (pairs (stream-cdr s) (stream-cdr t)))))
```

Currently I receive the following output when passing in identical prime streams

```
((2 2) (2 3) (3 3) (2 5) (3 5) ...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only pair-up the *adjacent* primes:

```
(define (stream-zip s t)
    (cons-stream
        (list (stream-car s) (stream-car t))
        (stream-zip (stream-cdr s) (stream-cdr t))))
```

Then you keep only the pairs of twins out of all adjacent pairs:

```
(define (twin primes)
  (stream-filter ...
    (stream-zip primes (stream-cdr primes))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a `(stream-filter (lambda (x) (= (- (cadr x) (car x)) 2)) ...)` at the obvious spot.

Comment: Do you mean inplace of stream-map?

Comment: C'mon, c'mon, is there really a chance, *ever*, for any non-adjacent primes to be twins ?!??? :)

Comment: @Will: I knew that. But it's often hard to know whether to answer the specific question posed by the author or to answer the larger question that the author should have asked, but didn't. In this case, the obvious answer is that you only need one stream of primes, not two. But instead of saying that, I just showed how to fix the specific problem the author noted. Your answer, of course, is better.

Comment: @user3277752: The filter goes at the outermost level of the function: (define (pairs s t) (stream-filter (lambda (x) (= (- (cadr x) (car x)) 2)) (cons-stream ...))). But you really should use only one prime stream, instead of two, as Will suggests.

Comment: @user448810 I just missed some little hint about this, some small remark about this... :) the OP's code computes the full cartesian product of primes with itself, it's *a little bit* of an overkill here... :) so I jumped. :)